# Get the selected object from dropdown

Tags: vuejs2

I have a categories list like below:

```
categories[
    {
        title: 'title1',
        id: 1
    },
    {
        title: 'title2',
        id: 2
    }
]
```

I am using [vue-select](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select) plugin. The HTML code is like below:`enter code here`

```
<v-select v-model="category" label="title" :on-change="setFeatures(// here what should I put?)" :options="categories"></v-select>
```

I want to get the selected object in the function `setFeatures` once the user selects it. I am getting it as `undefined` at the moment. Any help would be appreciated.

PS:
using Vuejs2 and plugin latest version.

Comment: `category` will have the selected object.

Comment: I tried that but got as undefined. I will check again.

Comment: @Pradeepb can you show the code where you try to access the `category` property?

Comment: my silly mistake :(. Earliar i had declared `category` in data as `category: {}`, it was dispalying {} in the select box and then I had removed it. thats the reason I was getting undefined. Thanks a lot for your time :) all working fine now.